# Add a class to each slide on a shopify slideshow

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a slideshow on my homepage on my shopify website. I have been given a task to add a class on each slide of the slideshow for google tag manager tracking on the anchor tag inside the "swiper-slide" div. I want to add the class based on the number of slides available. For example, for the first slide I want to add the class of "banner1", for 2nd slide "banner2" and so on. I tried the following:

`<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link}}" class="full-width-link banner{{forloop.index}}" ></a>`

but I end up having just "banner1" for all the slides.

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="main-swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    {% assign banner_index = forloop.index %}
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <a href="{{ block.settings.button_link}}" class="full-width-link " ></a>
      <!--<img src="{{ block.settings.image  | img_url: 'master'}}" class="img-responsive banner-img small--hide">
      <img src="{{ block.settings.mobimage | img_url: 'master' }}" class="img-responsive banner-img medium-up--hide">-->
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width:750px)" srcset="{{ block.settings.image  | img_url: '1600x'}}" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="img-responsive banner-img lazyload" >
        <img data-src="{{ block.settings.mobimage | img_url: '400x' }}" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" class="img-responsive banner-img lazyload">
      </picture>
      
      
      
      
      {% comment %}
      <div class="sticky--shop-box">
        <div class="slider--content setu-flex setu-direction-column height_100p">
          <p>{{ block.settings.subheading}}</p>
          <h1>{{ block.settings.slide_title}}</h1>
          {% if block.settings.button_label != blank %}
          <div class="hide shop-button--wrapper">
            <a href="{{ block.settings.button_link}}" class="hide btn brad_100 text-transform--none fw-500 btn--fill">{{ block.settings.button_label}}</a>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endcomment %}
    </div>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>
    
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: inside loop it must works, you make another mistake I think, you need to debug it properly.

Comment: Can you help me out? I'm new to liquid coding.

Comment: you able to share the actual code snapshot and page link on which it appiled?

Comment: Here's the link to the page https://setu.in/ . I need to make changes on the first fold, the slideshow on top.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
  <div class="swiper-slide-{{ forloop.index }}">
   </div>
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: I tried this, but its adding just the first index on all the slides.